# An extemal combinatorial design question. "Weak" steiner stystems.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

A Steiner system $S(t,k,\nu)$ is a collection $X$ of $\nu$ points and a collection of subsets of $X$ of size $k$ (frequently called blocks) such that each $t$ element subset of $X$ occurs in exactly $1$ of these blocks.

Steiner systems do not always exist, but it would be nice to find systems that don't necessarily satisfy all of the properties.  Specifically, a collection of blocks for some set $X$ such that every $t$ element subset occurs $\textbf{at most}$ once.  Until I find that this idea already has a name, I will refer to such a system as a weak Steiner system.

Let's look at an example to solidify this idea.  There does not exist a Steiner system $S(2,3,5)$ since Steiner triple systems (where $t=2$ and $k=3$) exist if and only if $\nu=1,3\pmod 6$.  However, we can look at weak Steiner systems in this case.  Denote the elements of $X$ by $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  Take, as our collection of blocks, $\{1,2,3\}$.  In this case, only the single block $\{1,2,3\}$.  Then this is a weak Steiner system for the case $(t=2,k=3,\nu=5)$.  This is, however, not a maximal weak Steiner system.  Indeed, I can take as my collection of blocks $\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\}$.  This too is a weak Steiner system, but with more blocks.  This design is maximal, and that fact can be quickly verified through a case by case argument.  In this case, I use the notation $D(2,3,5)=2$.  This means that the maximum number of blocks possible in a weak Steiner system (for these values of $t,k,\nu$) is $2$.

One more example, take $X$ to be the $6$ element set and denote its elements $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  I claim that $D(2,3,6)=4$.  Observe first that $X$ contains exactly $\binom{6}{2}=15$ distinct doubles, and each triple/block contains exactly $\binom{3}{2}=3$ doubles.  Hence, $D(2,3,6)\le 5$.  Since we know that a Steiner triple system does not exist in this case, we can conclude that $D(2,3,6)\le 4$.  Take as a collection of blocks $\{1,2,3\},\{1,4,5\},\{2,4,6\},\{3,5,6\}$ and observe that no double occurs more than once.  Hence, $D(2,3,6)=4$.

I am interested in determining this number for various values of $t,k,\nu$.  In the case when $t=2$, there is a generalization of this concept called the $H$ packing number of a graph $G$.  A packing of a graph $G$ is a collection of subgraphs of $G$ that are isomorphic to $H$ such that the collection of subgraphs are $\textbf{edge disjoint}$.  The most number of subgraphs isomorphic to $H$ in a packing is the packing number, denoted $P(H,G)$.  Specifically, when $t=2$, the packing number $P(K_k,K_\nu)$ is exactly the number I have been looking for, $D(2,k,\nu)$.  However, this, as far as I know, does not generalize to higher values of $t$, say $t=3$.

My question here is really a reference request.  Has this question of determining the most number of blocks in a "weak Steiner system" appeared before?  Has the notion of a "weak Steiner system" been researched before? What work has been done on this when $t\ge 3$?  Any nudge in the right direction would be helpful to me.

Here is a [relevant question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1751708/steiner-triple-system-with-lambda-le-1%22relevant%20question%22) that pertains to the case when $t=2$.
Here is a [link to a paper](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v4i1r1) where the $H$-packing number is discussed and defined.

Comment: In your example, you take a set $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and then take two blocks $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{4,5,6\}$. I'm assuming there is a typo. Also keep in mind that having a *maximal* weak $(t,k,v)$ Steiner system with size $m$ does not necessarily imply that $D(t,k,v)=m$. You may not be able to add more blocks to your example, but that doesn't mean there isn't a better example with more blocks.

Comment: @MorganRodgers  Thank you for the taking the time to respond.  Yes, these are mistakes.  I will edit my question with these fixes when I find the time to do so.